# What is the limit function of $f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x+\frac{y}{n})dy$

Tags: real-analysis

> $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Let $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x+\frac{y}{n})dy$. Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$.

By M.V.T for integral, $f_n(x) = \int_{x}^{x+1}f(\frac{y}{n})dy = f(\frac{c_x}{n}) $ for $\forall$ fixed $x$ . (Here $ x+1< c_x < x$)

Since the $f(x)$ is continuous, $f(\frac{c_x}{n})\to f(0)$ by squeeze thm.  ($f(0)$ is a limit function of the $f_n$). But the answer was $f(x)$. What did I wrong? And How to find the limit function?

Comment: $f_n(x) = \int_{x}^{x+1}f(\frac{y}{n})dy$ is not correct. The result follows immediately from Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the dominated convergence theorem ?

Comment: Another proof: $f_n(x)-f(x)=\int_0^{1} [f(x+\frac y n )-f(x)]dy$. Use unifrom continuity if $f$.

Comment: Okay. Then Why is the $\int_{x}^{x+1}f(\frac{y}{n})dy$ not correct? Does it hold  considering the translation of the $f(x+\frac{y}{n})$ to the $x$-axis as much as "$x$" ? (For fixed $x$)

Comment: Why is $f_n(x) = \int_{x}^{x+1}f(\frac{y}{n})dy$ not correct?  The correct result is $f_n(x) = \int_{nx}^{nx+1}f(\frac{y}{n})dy$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has
$$f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f\left(x+\frac{y}{n}\right)dy = \int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} nf(t) dt $$

the last step coming with the substitution $t = x + \frac{y}{n}$.

If $F$ denotes a primitive of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, you deduce that
$$f_n(x) = n\left(F\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-F\left(x\right)\right) = \frac{F\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-F\left(x\right)}{1/n}$$

In particular, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) = F'(x)$$

i.e.
$$\boxed{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a HW question and you should attempt it yourself enough times before reading the answer!

Notice that because the unit interval has length $1$, we have
$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dy
$$
So,
$$
f_n(x) - f(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x+\frac{y}{n}) - f(x)dy
$$
Take absolute values and use $ |\int g| \leq \int |g|$ to get
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \int_{0}^{1}|f(x+\frac{y}{n}) - f(x)| \ dy.
$$

Given $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N$ such that if $n > N$ then
$$
|f(x+\frac{y}{n}) - f(x)| < \epsilon, \ \text{for all $y \in [0,1]$}.
$$
Exercise: why?

So, by putting together the estimates we get

$$
n > N \implies \int_{0}^{1}|f(x+\frac{y}{n}) - f(x)| \ dy < \epsilon.
$$